# Nav background color changes upon scroll

Tags: javascript, onscroll

I want part of my navigation background to change color to match the content color as the user scrolls down.

An exact example of this is available at [blobfolio.com](http://www.blobfolio.com).

My attempt:

```
window.onscroll = function () {
    var background = document.body.scrollTop < 200 ? '#fff' : 'red',
        elems = document.getElementsByTagName('nav');

    for (var i=0; i<elems.length; i++) {
        elems[i].style.background = background;
    }
}
```

I think that it will include `for` loops. I have tried in this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fNn7K/275/) but the entire background changes, which isn't what I want.

I am really quite stuck, any help would be much appreciated!

Also I am trying to do this in pure JavaScript - no frameworks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this does what you're asking for:

```
window.onscroll = function () {
    var i = 0;
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("container");
    for(var j=elements.length-1; j>0; j--)
    {
        if (parseInt(elements[j].getBoundingClientRect().top) <= 0)
        {
            i = j;
            break;
        }
    }

    var nav = document.getElementsByClassName("nav");
    for (var j=0; j<nav.length; j++)
        nav[j].style.backgroundColor = "";

    nav[i].style.backgroundColor = window.getComputedStyle(elements[i]).getPropertyValue("background-color");
}

window.onscroll();
```

Here's a demo on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fNn7K/281/).

Doing it in pure JavaScript was quite fun :D

Comment: Thankyou! This is exactly what i was looking for. Sorry to be picky, but i noticed that the transition isn't smooth. When you slowly scroll down it doesnt switch from green to red where it should. Do you know how i could fix this?

Comment: This is due to `padding` - please find updated version here: http://jsfiddle.net/fNn7K/282/, though it gives you another weird effect :D (this is unavoidable, at least with the styling/structure you currently have, i think)

Comment: This is only a test as my styling will be completely different. How do i change that container size? When i put padding on the nav, the container color doesnt fit properly

Comment: Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/fNn7K/286/ will do the trick, I think. You can manipulate the side paddings, but the top/bottom ones affect only the given element and not the nav navigation (if that makes sense). Bear in mind as well that if the navigation will not be at the top of the page you'll have to take that into account as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this

```
window.onscroll = function () {
    var top=0;
    var top=document.body.scrollTop;
 if(top < 200){
     $("a[href='#home']").parent().css("background-color","Green");
         $("a[href='#home']").parent().siblings().css("background-color","");
       }

       if((top >= 200) && (top < 800)){
         $("a[href='#Services']").parent().css("background-color","red");
         $("a[href='#Services']").parent().siblings().css("background-color","");
       }    
}
```

[JS Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fNn7K/278/)

Sorry If you don't want to use Jquery. Here I am just giving you an idea to how to achieve that.

Comment: Thankyou, the only reason i wanted to use pure javascript is beacuse im not sure how to implement the jquery framework into my site, with a link?

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try. [Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/blunderboy/fNn7K/285/)

```
window.onscroll = function () {
    var offset = Math.max(document.documentElement.scrollTop, document.body.scrollTop),,
        lis = document.getElementsByTagName('li');

    var colorMap = [
        { value: 200, color : 'green'} ,
        { value: 800, color : 'red' },
        { value: 2800, color: 'purple'}
    ];

        var isColorSet = false;
         for (var i=0; i<colorMap.length; i++) {
             lis[i].style.background='black';
             if (!isColorSet && offset < colorMap[i].value) {
                 lis[i].style.background = colorMap[i].color;
                 isColorSet = true;
             }
        }
}
```

Let me know if it works for you.

Please find [Updated Demo Link here](http://jsfiddle.net/blunderboy/fNn7K/292/)

Comment: thanks, but i wanted each part of the nav ( home, services, etc) to change color to match the background, this only goes green and sticks

Comment: @Ned Try this now. It was a little cross browser issue. I have fixed it now. I have tried this both on chrome as well as on firefox now.

Comment: @Ned I have added updated link in my code. Please try it and let me know if you find it useful.

Comment: Yes this is what i have been spending the last hour trying to figure out! The only problem with your code is that because you have specified the "value" on different media screens its doesn't work because parts of the content are longer - if you know what i mean